# SSIS adding an existed package actually added an identical copy

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I try to add an existed package to a SSIS project using Visual Studio.  But it turns out the tool copies the package to a new package and name it as original name plus an incremented number first and then attach the package to the project.  I know I miss some settings.  But I could not find out what prevents the original package from attached.  Anyone encountered the same problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What is happening here is most likely that you have copied a package manually into the project directory and then tried to add it to the existing project.  BIDS (Visual Studio) assumes you are copying from a different location, takes the name and copies the project into your directory, finds an existing copy, and renames the new one to prevent name collision.

**Workaround #1** Before adding an existing object, move it to a temp directory outside of your project space.  Choose Add Existing package and copy into your project.  Package will have correct name.

**Workaround #2** After original scenario, delete the original from disk, then rename the copy from within BIDS (Visual Studio).  This will rename your package to the correct name.

Comment: Great solution.  Workaround #1 is the key: do NOT copy the .dtsx into your project folder first.  I thought this was clever, but it just makes VS (and, worse, TFS...) act up.

Answer (score 20):

The method you need to use to get around the "Add Existing Package" behavior is pretty simple. Just right-click on the ***project*** and select "Add Existing Item." Doing it this way just attaches the DTSX to the project without renaming or creating a copy.

Comment: You are correct, in newer versions this appears to have been fixed.  If you follow your steps it will properly just attach the dtsx.  In older versions it would always copy the dtsx regardless of option.

Comment: NOTE: If the file is read-only (due to source control provider for example) you must remove the read-only flag before this will work.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't want to lose the history from Git.

Answer (score 1):

The dtsx always gets copied into the solution folder, you're right, this has to be a bug.

The solution is to edit the .dtproj file within the solution folder such that the DTSPackages/DtsPackage/fullpath tag, reflects the location of the original dtsx package.