# SSIS - After 'exclude from project', how to re-include?

Tags: ssis

After I've excluded a package from a project by choosing Project->Exclude From Project, how do I 're-include' it later?

I thought it was Project->Add Existing Package, but that adds a *copy* of the package.

Comment: That should be how you do it.

Comment: I think it should be done in the same way we do for .net web app. Just click on solution or project and then under Solution explore tab you will see some 4-5 icons, on mouse over the icons you will see one of the icon says "show all files", click on that and you will your excluded file. now right click on file-> include in project. Though I have never done this in SSIS but guess similar functionality should be there.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909387/ssis-adding-an-existed-pacakge-actually-added-an-identical-copy

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy ,

*if it's old version of Visual Studio like 2012 ,*

just **Right Click on the folder > Add > Existing Item > choose the file which has been excluded**

*if it's old version of Visual Studio like 2008 ,*

**Right Click on the folder > Add > Include in Project**

[image: Right click on Folder > click Add > Existing Item > Select the file]

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015, I have found that I can re-include packages by right-clicking on the project and choosing `Add | Existing Item...` (**not** Existing Package).

It makes no sense, but it works.  I guess it will work the same in other versions of VS.

Comment: Caught me out with  2013 too.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, SSIS will copy your existing package and place the new copy into your project's folder location.  However, if your package is already in this location, it is supposed to just open the package.  Since you excluded the package, including it again should work fine without it making a copy of it.  The thing I notice, however, is that you don't mention getting an error.  Normally you would get an error if you were making a copy and it was being placed in the same location as the original.  Most like either you are renaming the package during the "Add Existing Package" stage, or your  package isn't in the correct location.

If your package is getting copied with a new name, I have found some indication that this might be a bug.  The work-around seems to be to then delete the original and rename the new copy.  It isn't pretty but it seems to be your best option.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, it's adding a "(1)" to the filename.

Comment: This is the only I found that works too. But why? Why is there no easy way to reinclude a package you just (accidently) excluded? It's one of those annoying things about SSIS

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you cant just "include" a package. Its more of an import which makes a copy... if the package already exists it adds a (1) to the name of the package.

This is the functionality for `SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio` that comes with `SQL server 2008 R2`. Doesn't make much sense but Im sure they fixed that in future `BIDS` releases